# Добавленный элемент в Spinner сразу не появляется

Tags: android, java

Через AlertDialog добавляю элемент в Spinner, но добавленный элемент сразу не появляется в Spinner,если перезапустить Fragment, он появляется. как решить проблему.
public class FragmentAdd extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

```
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();

    spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Button postButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    postButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Only allow posts if we have a location

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity());
            alert.setTitle("Create a Post");
            final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                    | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
            alert.setView(input);
            // Handle the dialog input
            alert.setPositiveButton("Post",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Create a post.

                            ParseObject group = new ParseObject("Group");
                            group.put("username",
                                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                            group.put("group", input.getText().toString());
                            group.saveInBackground();

                        }
                    });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // Do nothing.
                        }
                    });
            alert.create().show();
        }
    });

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    DataTask map;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        dataTask = new ArrayList<DataTask>();
        try {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Group");

            query.orderByAscending("group");

            ob = query.find();

            for (ParseObject group : ob) {

                map = new DataTask();
                map.setGroup((String) group.get("group"));
                // map.setDescription((String) group.get("description"));
                // map.setNametask((String) group.get("nametask"));

                dataTask.add(map);

            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.d("my", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml

        adapter = new SpinnerAdap(getActivity(), dataTask);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Я вижу, что сначала notifyDataSetChanged() вызываете, а потом только адаптер устанавливаете. Попробуйте очерёдность поменять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил по другому

etNTask = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etNTask);
        etDiscr = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDiscr);
        spGroup = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spGroup);
        spUsers = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spUsers);
        tvCal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCal);

```
    btnGroup = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnGroup);
    btnCal = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCal);
    btnSend = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

    // слушатель для кнопок
    btnGroup.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCal.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Установка настроенный запрос
    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AnywallPost>() {
        public ParseQuery<AnywallPost> create() {
            ParseQuery<AnywallPost> query = AnywallPost.getQuery();
            return query;
        }
    };

    // Установка адаптера запроса
    posts = new ParseQueryAdapter<AnywallPost>(getActivity(), factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(AnywallPost post, View view,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(getContext(),
                        R.layout.anywall_post_item, null);
            }
            TextView contentView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.contentView);
            contentView.setText(post.getText());
            return view;
        }
    };

    // Отключить автоматическую загрузку, когда адаптер подключен к зрения.
    posts.setAutoload(false);
    // Отключить нумерацию страниц, нам удастся запрос ограничимся
    posts.setPaginationEnabled(false);
    // Подключите адаптер запроса к представлению
    spGroup.setAdapter(posts);

private void doListQuery() {
    posts.loadObjects();
    parseAdapter.loadObjects();
}
```